# Can I run an application (notes - reminders previously) from Ubuntu touch on Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, 15.10, tablet, notes, evernote

I am looking for a native Evernote client for Linux. NixNote not meet my expectations. I heard about a new application, which is normally installed on Ubuntu Touch. It is called the "[Notes](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/community/core-apps/notes/)" before "[Reminders](https://launchpad.net/reminders-app)".

After installing from software center of Ubuntu, click on the application icon does not start (notes-app), in the case of reminders app white window opens.. I tried to use the "notes-app, reminders-app" in the terminal, flashed the message "command not found".

Hence my question. Can I use this app in Ubuntu 15.10 or just on Ubuntu Touch?

I wanted to test it in terms of usability, m.in creating indexes notes. I often use this feature. I'm thinking of buying the expected tablet software ubuntu, which convinced me the ability to connect to the monitor (portable pocket desktop fluid and responsive).

I often work with electronic notebook and the possibility of using the tablet on the big screen and the computer next to my dream. Now I use an old laptop with Windows on board - only for Evernote.

Answer (score 0):

### Where does the app run?

Your question whether this app can be used on Ubuntu 15.10 or just on Ubuntu Touch can be answered with the fact that in general it can run on both the desktop version and the tablet version, and on Ubuntu 15.04 the app works just fine (I ran the app today on 15.04) and on my bq Aquaris (which should be running Ubuntu Touch 15.04) it is running to.

However, on Ubuntu 15.10 it crashes and on launchpad there is a [bug report for notes-app](https://bugs.launchpad.net/notes-app/+bug/1520196) describing the problem of not being able to launch the app on desktop.

### Generalization

In general however, Ubuntu Touch apps can be run on the desktop, if one has the required libraries of Ubuntu Touch installed, which should be possible in most cases.

### Launching using an terminal

You said that you tried to start the app in the terminal, however that you failed. The reason is that the apps are a set of QML and similiar files, not typical compiled elf binaries, which must be interpreted by an compatible program. To run the app in terminal, you can either use `gtk-launch` which launches the application using its *.desktop files. The commands for the apps you named would be

```
$ gtk-launch com.ubuntu.reminders
$ gtk-launch notes-app
```

or you can directly use the interpreter `qmlscene`, e.g.

```
$ qmlscene /usr/share/notes-app/NotesApp.qml
```

---

I hope I could help you with this answer, and that the answer is acceptable. Sadly I don't know a simple solution to your problem, nor do I use the the apps much, so I can't help much.

Comment: Yes, it's the same problem as designated on the link to Bug # 1520196.

When I run other commands - ubuntu reminders - terminal displays messages:
Type NotesPage unavailable; 
Type EditNotePage unavailable; 
Type EditNoteView unavailable; 
module "Ubuntu.Content" is not installed.